# Configure OpenStack nova with remote Bind Server

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

How can we configure OpenStack to use and dynamically update remote Bind DNS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently supported. There is a DNS driver layer, but the only driver at the moment is for LDAP backed PowerDNS. I have code for dynamic DNS updates (https://review.openstack.org/#/c/25194/), but have had trouble getting it landed because we need to fix eventlet monkey patching first.

So, its in progress, but you probably wont see it until Havana is released.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack relies on dnsmasq internally.

I am not aware of any way integrate an external bind server.  Or plans to do that.  Or even a reason to do that.

Comment: Why wouldn't there be a reason to automatically create A records in a way that's consistent with an existing infrastructure? It's a huge boon to integrating teams and workflows with Openstack.

Comment: Not saying it isn't a good idea.  In fact it's probably a great idea.  Just there is no project I know of addressing it, and certainly nothing with foundation buy in.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Designate (https://docs.openstack.org/developer/designate/)

This could be what you are looking for:

```
Designate provides DNSaaS services for OpenStack:

- REST API for domain & record management
- Multi-tenant support
- Integrated with Keystone for authentication
- Framework in place to integrate with Nova and Neutron notifications (for auto-generated records)
- Support for PowerDNS and Bind9 out of the box
```

[image]